# Listen to HTTP Request to trigger some action

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I am using a 3rd party app Bt.tn which provides me a virtual button to press.

On pressing the virtual bttn, a HTTP request to [URL](http://livingwellnessmedicalcenter.com/bt_tn.html) which I choose is originated.

Now I am trying to listen to this originated Request on my URL so that whenever the bttn is pressed, I want to trigger some action like `alert()`.

I have tried using this piece of code but it doesn't help:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(event,request, settings){
    alert("I just listened to a bt.tn request!");
});
```

Can anyone help me on this?
Thanks!

Comment: The provided link is not accessible it requires a login

Comment: It's just a big button which hits my URL with GET/POST request.

Comment: But it has an api, how does the implementation of that button looks like?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `ajaxComplete` only works for requests that were made using jQuery and i can't see how the button is implemented

Comment: @dcohenb Does this help? http://requestb.in/pz8akepz?inspect

Comment: No, i need to see how you're using the button. what's the API used for it.